# Maximizing a function over a list

Tags: list-manipulation, mathematical-optimization

Suppose I want to efficiently maximize an arbitrary function `f` over a list of argument values. (E.g. maximize the `Sin[x]` over the possible `x`-values `{1., 2., 3., 4.}`) and find the index of that maximum value. This is the easiest way I could think of to do it:

```
maxVal[f_, vals_] := Block[{fvals = f /@ vals},
vals[[Position[fvals, Max[fvals]][[1, 1]]]]
]
```

For example, `maxVal[Sin, {1., 2., 3., 4.}]` returns `2.`.

(Note that the expression `Position[fvals, Max[fvals]][[1, 1]]` above is equivalent to the simpler expression `Sort[fvals][[1]]`, but I believe that the latter expression is slower to calculate because it needs to sort the entire list instead of just keeping track of its lowest value.)

This seems very cumbersome to me - is there an easier way to do it using built-in Mathematica functions?

Comment: Have you seen `MaximalBy[]`?

Comment: @J.M. Nope, but that's exactly what I needed! If you convert to an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: @J.M. Is there an "arg min" version of `MaximalBy` that returns the index of the maximal element of the list, or do I need to use `Position`?

Comment: Have you checked out `Ordering`?

Comment: @J.M. I.e. `Position[vals, #][[1]]& /@ MaximalBy[vals,f]`, which is also rather cumbersome

Comment: @CarlWoll I believe that `Ordering` is inefficient for the same reason as `Sort`.

Comment: Look at the 2 arg form, e.g. `Ordering[values, -1]`

Comment: As Carl says, the two-argument form of `Ordering[]` is what you want here.

Comment: Could anyone explain why they voted to close this question as off-topic? (I don't mind the votes, I'm just curious what's off-topic about this question - If I've misunderstood this site's scope, I want to avoid posting future off-topic questions.)

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

```
maxVal[f_, vals_] := Ordering[Thread[f[vals]], {-1}]
```

### Performance

```
First@RepeatedTiming[maxVal[Sin, RandomReal[{-9, 9}, 10^7]]]
```

> ```
> 0.838
> ```

```
ListPlot[
 Table[
  {10^n, First@RepeatedTiming[maxVal[Sin, RandomReal[{-9, 9}, 10^n]]]}
  , {n, 1, 8}
  ]
 , ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}
 , PlotTheme -> "Scientific"
 , FrameLabel -> {"List Length", "Time [s]"}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

Based on J.M. and Carl Woll's helpful comments, it seems that the quickest way to find the maximum value is `MaximalBy[vals, f]` and the quickest way to find its index is `Ordering[f/@vals, -1][[1]]`.

By the way, I ran

```
rands = RandomReal[1, 10^7];
Timing[ord = Ordering[rands]; ord[[1]]]
Timing[Ordering[rands, 1][[1]]]
```

and verified that the two-argument form of `Ordering` is indeed far more efficient that just taking the first element of the one-argument form - the two-argument form doesn't sort the entire list, but only as much of the list as is needed.